# htaccess - Forcing trailing slash but exempt .shtml files

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, .htaccess

I tried the following code to force a trailing slash on my website:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

And it works but when I went to a page that should throw a 404, it is redirecting me to `www.domain.com/404.shtml` which goes in a redirect loop.

The site is: http://www.shivampaw.com

I have removed the above code from the htaccess but still need the trailing slash forced.

My full htaccess rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^services(/)*$ ./services.php
RewriteRule ^contact(/)*$ ./contact.php
RewriteRule ^about(/)*$ ./about.php
RewriteRule ^work(/)*$ ./work.php
RewriteRule ^work/prima-healthcare(/)*$ ./my-work/primahc.php
RewriteRule ^work/medical-studies-europe(/)*$ ./my-work/mse.php
RewriteRule ^work/rowley-village-nursery(/)*$ ./my-work/rvn.php
```

The question is: **How Can I Force The Trailing Slash Without Affecting My Clean URLS Rewrite Rules**

Comment: Please clearly state your question.

Comment: @Alex, how can I force a trailing slash in my htaccess. The code i've used from other questions hasn't worked (probably because of my clean urls rewrite rule.